# Paste entire column from excel to SAP ECC table

Tags: excel, copy-paste, sap-erp

I often need to paste a column of values from excel into a SAP GUI ECC table. However, it will only paste values into the fields currently visible in ECC meaning I have to scroll down in the table, reselect my data, and paste again. Is there a simple way to paste the entire column in one go?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use paste button in order to paste all your records.[image]